# Greenaddress - client too old

Tags: bitcoin-wallet-app, green-address

I've got an Android phone with Greenaddress on it, that I've been effectively using as cold storage. I've now put it online to get my BTC off it, and when I try the transaction (using a legacy address) it goes through two factor authentication, but when I enter the code it just says `client too old`!

There's no Greenaddress to update to on the Play store, so I tried installing 'Green' as it's by the same people, but it says there's no wallet!

EDIT: worse still, most of it is gone! Was it compromised?!!
What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I also was using Greenaddress wallet.  I now use Blockstream Green (The website is https://blockstream.com/green/)
After I downloaded/installed app, I used recover wallet and used the passphrase created when wallet was made in greenaddress.  I now can see my wallet balance again.